# sklearn-metrics of regression reasonable while cross-validation returns huge number

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am a beginner, following a tutorial from Aurelien Geron book on ML with SKLEARN. 
When testing my prediction with the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

listings_predictions = lin_reg.predict(listings_prepared)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(listings_labels, listings_predictions)
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
lin_rmse
```

I am getting `51.96`. (seems very reasonable)

Now, when I run the cross-validation of the same method, I am getting values out of this world:

```
lin_scores = cross_val_score(lin_reg, listings_prepared, listings_labels,
                             scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
lin_rmse_scores = np.sqrt(-lin_scores)
display_scores(lin_rmse_scores)


   Scores: [5.33624445e+01 2.96290932e+10 5.25981399e+01 5.29672973e+01
     1.26397404e+11 5.17644346e+01 5.10301124e+01 5.45672660e+01
     6.69753606e+11 4.29844291e+11]
    Mean: 125562439481.52774
    Standard deviation: 221930379288.67526
```

Can you advise where to even look for the source of the problem? How could regression be a "bit off", and the cross-validation  of the same be billion times higher?

Comment: Check your dataset for outliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reformat your cross validation scores, they are:

          `53.3624445
 29629093200.0
          52.5981399
          52.9672973
126397404000.0
          51.7644346
          51.0301124
          54.567266
669753606000.0
429844291000.0`

Like BlackBear said, this is a sign that there are likely some outliers in four of your CV partitions. These are the error scores on test sets for each individual run of cross validation, so if there is an outlier in one, that means the model did not have it as an example to learn from in its training set. When you used all of the data for training without CV, the model had those outlier examples to learn from.