# Cross_val_score returns huge numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

```py
Ln = LinearRegression()

Ln.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(np.mean(cross_val_score(Ln, X_train, y_train, scoring= "neg_mean_absolute_error", cv= 2)))
```

The results I get back are huge numbers, I have found below link that might explain my issue, but doesnt offer solutions
[sklearn-metrics of regression reasonable while cross-validation returns huge number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732484/sklearn-metrics-of-regression-reasonable-while-cross-validation-returns-huge-num)

What solutions do you suggest?

By the way, when I change the test to lasso regression, I do not deal with the issue, which is why I suspect the issue not being because of outliers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the issue when adding regularization, you likely have [collinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) features.

Feature collinearity is an issue because in can result in an unregularized optimization having an infinite number of solutions with near-equivalent training loss that do not generalize.

Ridge or elasticnet regularization are better than Lasso regularization when collinear features are present because they particularly penalize very large coefficients.

Comment: I removed two variables and the issue went away, but, when I do a mean absolute error analysis with the variables included on the whole train data(no cross validation) I get 0.24, which is a good score. I guess my issue now is I do not understand really if the problem is caused by collinearity or outliers, maybe both? Thanks

Comment: Developing models is both an art and a science, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703596/13631591) shows a good first pass at identifying possible collinearity at your data

Comment: I have also heard that collinearity does not reduce predictive power, which is my case.